# Intellij code completion, showing method/constructor parameter types and variable names

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-13, intellij-plugin

I find this extremely annoying that you often do not get help with figuring out the parameter signatures of methods and contructors when you have already written the first parameter.

Instead Intellij will show the variables available to you in your context. This is good, but not the first prio. I want to see the signature of the method/constructor as well.

This has the consequence that you always have to keep deleting and CTRL + SPACE to see the signature.

Is there a way around this issue?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> to show the signature(s) of the method/constructor, see this link for more details:

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/viewing-method-parameter-information.html

Answer (score 19):

You don't have to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, you can configure **IDEA** to always show this information:

Go to **`Settings`** > **`Editor`** > **`General`** > **`Code Completion`**

Select the `Show full signatures` and `Autopopup in (ms:)` boxes.

[image: Intellij Idea - Configure-Editor-Code-Completion]

Comment: Yeah, the ctrl-p is still useful when editing a method that already exists.

Comment: Actually, it will disappear if this box is inactivated for some reason. You can get it back with CTRL + P